# Cannot build static Nuxt3 app to be deployed in subfolder

Tags: nuxt.js, amazon-cloudfront, subdirectory, nuxtjs3

We're tryng to deploy a Nuxt3 single page application in a subfolder but something is missing.

##### The big picture

We're using an AWS cloudfront distribution to serve a Nuxt3 static single page application from an S3 bucket, and now we have to add a whole private section to the application that needs to be served when visiting the `/private` url.

The old application has lots of issues, from code quality to ci/cd configuration and all that in between, so we opted to start a new one and incrementally migrate the old one to this.

The new app is compiled to static files and deployed to a second bucket in the `private` folder (distribution still have access to the entire bucket), we updated the distribution as needed and now it has 2 origins and its behaviors looks like this:

**Origins**

```
Origin name Origin domain                           Origin path     Origin type Origin shield region    Origin access
OldBucket   old-bucket.s3.<region>.amazonaws.com                    S3          -                       <origin-access>
NewBucket   new-bucket.s3.<region>.amazonaws.com                    S3          -                       <origin-access>
```

**Behaviors**

```
Precedence  Path pattern    Origin      Protocol policy Policy name
0           /private/*      OldBucket   HTTP and HTTPS  Managed-CachingOptimized    -   -
1           /*              NewBucket   HTTP and HTTPS  Managed-CachingOptimized    -   -
2           Default (*)     OldBucket   HTTP and HTTPS  Managed-CachingOptimized    -   -
```

So it should serve old spa as default and new one when vising `<distribution-domain>/private`.

##### The problem experienced

When starting a new anonymous session to `<distribution-domain>` the old app is served correctly, but when navigating to `<distribution-domain>/private` a 403 is returned.

I have to explicitly add `index.html` to the url and then something weird happens: I can see from the browser dev panel that all the new app static generated files are returned with no error (i.e. index.html, 7 compiled js files and the favicon), but after all of these a js from main domain is returning a 403, like something is still referencing the old app.

Another strange thing is that a nuxt page with the message 'This page could not be found' is returned, but it is not the 404 page since I tried to overwrite it with my own custom `pages/404.vue`.
I suspect it is from the new app since the only html returned is its one, but the 'Back to the home page' link point to main ditribution domain and not to the `private` path as it is the from the old app.

##### App configuration

I've set new app configuration `baseUrl` variable in `nuxt.config.js` as follows

```js
app: {
    baseURL: process.env.BASE_URL,
  }
```

and the generated `index.html` correctly reference all the js assets in the `private` folder, that is (I assume) confirmed from having all of them being correctly loaded when visiting `<distribution-domain>/private/index.html`.

##### Where's the problem?

I cannot figure out where the problem lies, but the cloudfront distribution seems working correctly serving files from the expected bucket (except it is not serving `index.html` file by default from second origin while doing so from the other), so probably I've wrongly configured the new application but can't understand what is missing/misconfigured.

## Update #1

Looking closely I noticed that the wrong downloading script file is actually "duplicate" of another one correctly downloaded (both red underlined), but this second attempt to be downloaded is caused by another script (blue underlined).

**Browser downloads**
[image]

Checking the blue underlined script I found this code portion

```js
var f,script=document.createElement("script");script.charset="utf-8",script.timeout=120,c.nc&&script.setAttribute("nonce",c.nc),script.src=function(e){return c.p+""+{2:"a7af018",3:"021aa29",4:"04f2efd",5:"705a116",6:"af31a11",7:"9f010d4",8:"8e352a3"}[e]+".js"}(e)
```

So it looks like it is trying to create a `script` section in the page to import the other scripts, but just one lead to the miscreated url problem, while the others doesn't (I assume somehow their urls are being correctly created, thus not being re-download as already done by `index.html`).